# Active High Switch interfacing in 8051

Tags: 8051

How to read an Active high switch in 8051 micro controller ?. 8051 requires port pin to be high while reading.So making pin to be low and continuously reading the pin for high signal doesn't working. What to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can CONNECT switch with INT0 OR INT1 PIN of 8051 microcontroller and use switch as **external interrupt**.

Comment: But both are active low interrupt.Actually I was trying polling method for AH switch.I used Port0. Followed this sequence...P0=0x00; P0=0xFF; and connected AH swich to port 0. Its working in keil debugger. I think its working for P0 since it doesn't have pull up resistor.

Comment: Maybe P0! But 8051 all ports are by default high whenever reset or power up,maybe you need to change if your first  switch data is high

Comment: I just checked it in the hardware. The method I said is working.Thank you.

Comment: Hi,
You can use pull down method for any port pin of 8051. I never use this but I thought this might be work.
Let's know us if you sucess in.